# Different ghostscript versions have different compression behaviour

Tags: compression, ghostscript

I call this command on GS 9.22 and GS 9.55 versions:

`gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=myOutput.pdf myInput.pdf`

Using GS 9.22 version I can compress a certain PDF file from 8.5 MB to about 5.5 MB. Using GS 9.55 version on the same original file there is no compression at all.

Is this a bug in GS 9.55 version or is there a change in behavior?

Comment: It is totally impossible to tell without having the original file. Or at the very least the two created files.

Comment: Ok, thought someone knows that there is an issue. Nevertheless, as gs 9.22 and gs 9.55 behave different on the same file there must be a difference. I try to find a small example with uncritical content.

Comment: Hmmm ... cannot find a proper example. The issue came from a scanned file that had to go through OCR (which I did with pytesseract). Operating on "original" PDFs results in same compression rate. Operation on already compressed, scanned files can result in different compression rates. For the mentioned special file I had totally different results. Probably this has something to do with the internal default resolution of images inside the PDF?!

Comment: It's really pretty much impossible to tell. However if the effective resolution of the image in the PDF (the area covered divided by the number of pixels in each direction) is less than the threshold defined for the ebook setting, then the image won't be further downscaled. Since scanned images are large they will tend to dominate the content of such a PDF and any other changes will likely be small. SO essentially yes, it's due to the content. But I can't be certain without seeing the file.